# Conjecture on Prime Numbers and Exponential Equipment

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures

How to generate a rigorous proof for - 
The specific conjecture which states that we can always frame every Prime number in an exponentially framed equation with perfect cubes & squares. I'll present the respective segments of the conjecture and its Prototype.

**Conjecture's statement -**

**The square of every Prime number can be expressed as a sum or difference of some perfect cube and any another Prime**

Mathematical Structure
**$a^3 \pm P_{k} = P^2_n$ , $a,n, k\in\mathbb{N}$ ,  Where $P_m$ denotes the $m$th Prime respectively .**

Progress on Initial inputs and outputs-

$\begin{array}{||c || c ||}
\hline
a^3 \pm p_k& p_n^2 \\
\hline
 1+3& 2^2\\
\hline
512-503& 3^2\\
\hline
8+17& 5^2\\
\hline
8+41& 7^2\\
\hline
8+113& 11^2\\
\hline
216-47& 13^2\\
\hline
8+281& 17^2\\
\hline
8+353& 19^2\\
\hline
8+521& 23^2\\
\hline
1728-887& 29^2\\
\hline
8+953& 31^2\\
\hline
8+1361& 37^2\\
\hline
1728-47& 41^2\\
\hline
8000-6151& 43^2\\
\hline
216+1993& 47^2\\
\hline
8+2801& 53^2\\
\hline
512+2969& 59^2\\
\hline
512+3209& 61^2\\
\hline
8+4481& 67^2\\
\hline
1728+3313& 71^2\\
\hline
216+5113& 73^2\\
\hline
1728+4513& 79^2\\
\hline
216+6673& 83^2\\
\hline
8000-79& 89^2\\
\hline
...\pm...& 97^2\\
\hline
...\pm...& 101^2\\
\hline
...\pm...& 103^2\\
\hline
\end{array}$

**Conjecture's Prototype**

**The sum or difference of square of every Prime Number with some Perfect cube yields any another Prime number.**

Mathematical Structure 
**$(m^3 \pm P^2_{b} = P_c)$, $m,b,c \in\mathbb{N}$ and $P_n$ is the nth Prime Number respectively.**

The above parent equation can be framed in other $3$ ways aslike -

$P_c - m^3 = \pm P^2_b$ which clearly generates the expression for square of every Prime number as per the conjecture constraints.

$|P_c - m^3| = |P^2_b|$ where taking modulus yields positive results, $P_c \mp P^2_b =m^3$

Initial inputs and outputs-

$\begin{array}{||c || c ||} 
 \hline
 P_c - m^3 & \pm P_b^2 \\ 
 \hline\hline
  31-27& 2^2\\ 
 \hline 
17-8& 3^2\\ 
 \hline 
89-64& 5^2\\ 
 \hline 
113-64& 7^2\\ 
 \hline 
337-216& 11^2\\ 
 \hline 
233-64& 13^2\\ 
 \hline 
353-64& 17^2\\ 
 \hline 
577-216& 19^2\\ 
 \hline 
593-64& 23^2\\ 
 \hline 
887-1728& -29^2\\ 
 \hline 
2689-1728& 31^2\\ 
 \hline 
1433-64& 37^2\\ 
 \hline 
1063-2744& -41^2\\ 
 \hline 
1913-64& 43^2\\ 
 \hline  
2273-64& 47^2\\ 
 \hline 
3023-5832& -53^2\\ 
 \hline 
3697-216& 59^2\\ 
 \hline 
5449-1728& 61^2\\ 
 \hline 
6217-1728& 67^2\\ 
 \hline 
8783-13824& -71^2\\ 
 \hline 
5393-64& 73^2\\ 
 \hline 
\end{array}$

The parameter $a$ in Primary conjecture and the parameter $m$ in its prototype takes infinitely many but unique values .

In order to prove it , one needs to overcome a new level of challenges it brings in Number theory ,
So far many efforts have been made to prove the Conjecture but we couldn't prove it for every value of $a$ & $m$ respectively.

Aops community on internet has made efforts on it [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/q2h1885391p12842764)
Providing hypothesis... Proving a special case ... Hope we get to see a well defined constructive proof which even generalizes the Special case within itself.

Comment: I can't find it now, but I recall a very similar question on this site just a few days ago. That  post might have some useful info. for you in any comments and/or answers.

Comment: Actually It was mine post which I deleted few days ago, aslike it really needed to framed in MSE culture.

Comment: As it is your question doesn't make sense because almost every such problem about prime numbers is unprovable at least with the tools we have access to. Thus to ask for a (dis)proof you need to find some approach / article letting us think that problem is the exception and is provable.

Comment: Closest I got was examining it mod 9 where there are only 4 squares ( 0,1,4,7); and 3 cubes (0,1,8). which can force you onto which arithmetic progressions of primes ?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Thanks gentlemen , but it'll be more helpful if we get to see more elaborated work of yours mentioned here. I strongly suggest framing your work and putting it here ,

Comment: Yeah, and I strongly suggest you stop trying to get orhers to work on this.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Why you think so?

Comment: Well reuns comment goes a long way in convincing me. But honestly posting multiple times instead of editing, is a hallmark of a crank.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee In fact I think reworking your own post, when the first version was inappropriate for this site, is a good way. As one can see: he/she learned his lesson. However, I find the phrasing of *reuns* comment - even though he might be right, and I am willing to understand this - not fitting for welcoming a new user of MSE.

Comment: That's what the edit link is for. I don't see much learning going on. It does not take 3 times posting the same, to learn to post information. This site isn't a welcome anyone affair.

Comment: my(a=vector(9,i,Mod(i,9)^2),b=vector(9,i,Mod(i,9)^3));apply(r->apply(q->lift(q),r),setbinop((c,d)->[c-d,-1,d-c,1,c,d],b,a))
%11 = [[0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, -1, 0, 1, 1, 1], [1, -1, 8, 1, 1, 0], [1, -1, 8, 1, 8, 7], [2, -1, 7, 1, 0, 7], [3, -1, 6, 1, 1, 7], [4, -1, 5, 1, 8, 4], [5, -1, 4, 1, 0, 4], [6, -1, 3, 1, 1, 4], [7, -1, 2, 1, 8, 1], [8, -1, 1, 1, 0, 1], [8, -1, 1, 1, 8, 0]]

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee With my humble request to you, would you explain what's that data you've putted on ?! I've no idea what it is .

Comment: Code and it's output. language : PARI/GP